# Why Number values are limited in programming languages?

Tags: java

```
long  –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to  9 ,223,372,036,854,775,807
int   –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
short – 32,768 to 32,767
byte  – 128 to 127
```

Why number values are limited ?. What happens If we have unique identifier for identifying a user for my web application  . Example : Facebook , Google+ . They have billions of users . What datatype are they using to store unique identifiers . If they use `string` datatypes how can they use `>` and `<` operators .  Is there any reason to restrict the number value?.

Thanks ,
Kannan

Comment: U see `long`'s max value there? Its about a billion billion. Doesnt that cover your question?

Comment: How big is a bit and how many bits can a processor process?

Comment: why would you want to use `>` and `<` on an id? And you realized that a long would be enough for billions of users?

Comment: Side note: in C++ for example, any operator like `>` or `<` can be rewritten to match the application's needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the ranges are restricted is that every numeric type occupies a certain number of bytes. This dictates the range of the type.

For example, with two bytes it is only possible to represent values from -32,768 to 32,767 (or from 0 to 65,535 if using an unsigned type).

> They have billions of users.

In your example, `long` is clearly wide enough to represent billions of values (and even `int` is good for a couple of billion).

> If they use string datatypes how can they use > and < operators.

Firstly, you *can* compare strings using [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Secondly, it's not even clear *why* you'd need to compare user ids in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

It all stems from memory management. Computer programs need to know how much memory will a variable use during its lifetime, hence the limited values.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about numeric representation in computer's binary numbers. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_number_format) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

Answer (score 1):

this has to do with the way [numbers are represented in computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_number_format) we use binary bits to represent (at the hardware level) numbers. so if you use one binary bit you can represent two numbers. 0 and 1 (of course, depending on your interpretaion, they can be any two numbers). now if you use 2 binary bits you can represent 4 numbers 00,01,10, and 11. the next bit gives you 8 numbers and so on. see the pattern ? its always 2 to the power of the number of bits available.

now when we say byte we (usually) mean 8 bits. which means 2^8 possible numbers. however we usually reserve one bit for the sign (possitive or negative). so we get 2^7 numbers equally spread out around zero. or – 128 to 127 as you put it. (this is somewhat of a simplification as [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) complicates things a bit more).

tl;dr : the reason we "restrict" number ranges is because of hardware limitations.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be restricted. Think about how big a number can be and how many bytes is required to represent them? Also the CPU and the RAM has various limitations like number of bits that be processed at a time.

Also, check out the reason why Java deprecated the Date class and recommended the Calendar class. Calendar class provides better ways of representing time rather than in term of milliseconds since epoch which is a really big number; much bigger than number of Facebook users perhaps.

That said, Java provides `java.math.BigInteger` and `java.math.BigDecimal` for working with really big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The integer number types are limited due to the way they are stored in memory. It comes down to binary (the 1s and 0s at the basis of all computing).

A Byte is 8 bits (binary digits), the most data 8 bits can store is 2^8, which is 256, when split in half to allow negatives, this gives the -128 to 127 range you quoted, or 0 to 255 if you use an unsigned type. (Note this doesn't go to 256, as 0 is a value that also needs representing)

The same goes for all of the other ranges, but with larger numbers of bits. So, the reason for using limited numbers is to save on memory.

Systems that require higher numbers can use more memory to store the data, there is no inherent limit except the system memory.

Answer (score 0):

I bet Google+, Facebook and so on don't use numbers for user identifiers. There are other types that could be used for that. For example GUID which means global unique identifier. It looks like a string, contains numbers letters and dashes some times and its guaranteed to be unique by the database.

And also I doubt they need to compare exactly the ids of the users.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what facebook uses... I think once I've seen an facebook api answer with number for id :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why number values are limited ?.

The reason type are not unlimited is because the resources of your machine are not unlimited.

Instead it is natural to reduce both memory and CPU consumed to use data type which are easily implemented in hardware.  This means data types which are multiples of bytes (standardised as 8 bits) and powers of 2 of bytes.  This determines the number of unique values each data type can have.  Java limited this further by having only one unsigned type on the basis AFAIK that signed types are more natural to deal with.

This is why these types are limited

```
byte - signed 8 bits => -2^7 to 2^7-1
char - unsigned 16-bits => 0 to 2^16-1
short - signed 16-bits => -2^15 to 2^15-1
int - signed 32-bits => -2^31 to 2^31-1
long - signed 64-bit => -2^63 to 2^63-1
```

> What happens If we have unique identifier for identifying a user for my web application.

Unique identifiers are usually limited and encoded with base 36 or higher.

> Example : Facebook , Google+ . They have billions of users .

A `long` has one billion, billions so this is preety small number by comparison. ;)

> What datatype are they using to store unique identifiers.

64-bit values would be mroe than enough.

> If they use string datatypes how can they use > and < operators .

For ids, they don't need to use such operators, only == and !=.

> Is there any reason to restrict the number value?.

Because your machine is not unlimited and you want to make the best use of the hardware you have.

Answer (score -1):

you can create your variable as you want.

```
public class MyVariable{
    public byte variable;
    MyVariable(int a){
        variable = new byte[a];
    }
}
```